# Constructing an entire function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, hadamard-product

This is a question from my complex analysis final exam: Does there exists an entire function $f$ such that $f(\log k)=1/\log k$ for all $k\geq 2$, integer. My answer is a no. What do you guys think?

Comment: Shall $k$ be fixed or do you mean $\forall k\ge 2$? If it is fixed this works for $f(x)=x,  k=e$.

Comment: Is this for real $k$ or integer $k$?

Comment: for all $k$, sorry that was a typo. If that is the case, then this is completely trivial

Comment: More generally, you can find an entire function with any prescribed values on a set without finite limit points.  But for a set with a finite limit point, there is uniqueness...

Comment: @RobertIsrael all real $k$

Comment: Then why bother talking about $\log k$?  Why not just say $f(x) = 1/x$ for all $x \ge \log 2$?

Comment: $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, my bad, I typed up the hypothesis for a different problem. So $f(\log k)=1/\log k$ for integer valued $k\geq 2$

Comment: It matters that the set is discrete. You cannot specify the values on a continuum, nor can you specify values on, for example, $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. But yes, provided $\{ z_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is discrete, for any $\{ y_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ you can always define an entire function with $f(z_n)=y_n$. This case just uses particular numbers.

Comment: @Ian This should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

It matters here that the set is discrete. In general you cannot specify the values of an entire function on a continuum, nor on, for example, $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (a set with a finite limit point). But when $\{ z_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is discrete, for any sequence $\{ y_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ there is an entire function $f$ with $f(z_n)=y_n$. When $y_n \equiv 0$ for instance, the Weierstrass factorization theorem will do the job for you.